# Bootstrap Modal showing grey and progress

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-modal

i have a Bootstrap Modal

```
<div id="responsive" class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Responsive</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4>Some Input</h4>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4>Some More Input</h4>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
                <p><input class="form-control" type="text"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#responsive">
    New Cash Account
</button>
```

when i click every thing goes funny like this, why? help please!!!!

this application i in MVC 5 and using the bootstrap scaffolding

[image: result screen]
[image: when it shoudl display]

when it shoudl display

Comment: Is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/3LWqf/; have you got an ajax call or something else that hangs the application?

Comment: no i have nothing, i think this is something to do with my mvc scaffolding. but i am not using anything different than the std provided by the MVC 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 (as your question is tagged), requires the `modal-content` to wrapped in `modal-dialog` div..

```
<div id="responsive" class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               ...
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/123094

The progress-bar may be some to other conflicting element on your page.